# Angular Input box value input restrictions

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want an input box in angular which only accepts value 0-5 and decimal value upto unit place from 1 to 9 which is optional.

Example

```
    1. 0 (correct)
    2. 0.0(incorrect)
    3. 0.1(correct)
    4. 1.5(correct)
```

Also don't take decimal if value entered 5 decimals are allowed only for values(0-4)

Example

```
    1. 5(correct)
    2. 5.9(incorrect)
    3. 4.9(correct)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a custom validator following the official docs: [Defining custom validators](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#defining-custom-validators)